# In Scrapy, how to select based on matching the URL of a link to a regular expression

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape [APKmirror.com](http://www.apkmirror.com) download pages such as http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/shareit-technologies-co-ltd/shareit-connect-transfer/shareit-3-0-38_ww-release/shareit-3-0-38_ww-android-apk-download/ in a reliable manner.

I've started the Scrapy shell from the command line with

```
scrapy shell http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/shareit-technologies-co-ltd/shareit-connect-transfer/shareit-3-0-38_ww-release/shareit-3-0-38_ww-android-apk-download/
```

I'm currently trying to scrape the developer name, app name, and version name from the top navigation bar:

[image]

which in this case are "SHAREit Technologies Co.Ltd", "SHAREit - Transfer & Share", and "3.0.38_ww", respectively.

So far I've come up with the following XPath expression for the developer name:

```
In [84]: response.xpath('//*[@class="site-header-contents"]//nav//a/text()').extract()[0]
Out[84]: u'SHAREit Technologies Co.Ltd'
```

For the app and version names I would replace `[0]` with `[1]` and `[2]`, respectively. The problem is that using numerical indices is not considered good scraping practice.

Rather, I'd like to use the 'real' distinguishing feature between these links: the fact that their URLs contain different numbers of slashes (`/`). I would like to define a custom selector which matches the `a/@href` against a regular expression and if it matches, returns the `a/text()`, but I wasn't able to figure out how to do this. (For example, the `re` method (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.XPathSelector.re) seems to be usable as a substitute for `extract()`, but not to 'aid' the selection process).

How can I select based on a custom function applied to the `@href`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it's not necessarily a bad practice in this case if you're extracting data from the breadcrumbs. You can guarantee that the breadcrumb order will always be the same - first item is the company, second is the product and last is the version - pretty predictable!
Nonetheless you might want to use more reliable xpath indexing instead:

```
"//div/a[1]" 
# would get first <a> node under <div>
"//div/a[last()]"
# would get last <a> node under <div>
```

However, to answer your question, there is `re:test` xpath evaluator which allows you to test something with regular expresions.

Find `<div>` node that has `<a>` node child with .com href:

```
"//div[re:test(a/@href, '.+?\.com')]"
```

Find `<div>` node that contains some text insensitive regex match:

```
"//div[re:test(.//text(), 'foo.bar', 'i')]"
```